# How to reuse threads in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, osmdroid

I have an OSMDroid MapView with an ItemizedIconOverlay on it.
Every time user scrolls map, an event fires to load data for newly visible map area and update overlay. 
The problem is that this way we need a lot threads to handle connections and I want to find a way to reuse a thread or Runnable class. Is it possible? Can I share a Runnable instance between threads? If I work with threads that way, how can I update MapView inside UI thread?

Comment: Have you taken a look at AsyncTask? It was built for things like this. If you are worried about allocating too many threads then you can create a thread-pool using the Executor classes.

Comment: It should be re-using the threads already.  I can not remember how many get made but its not a stupidly big number.  Are you seeing a real problem like running out of memory?